# How to support embedded maps (with custom value types) in MongoDB GORM?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I would like to have an embedded document referred to by a map (as in 'class A' below). The environment is Grails + GORM + MongoDB.

is that possible, and if yes, how?

```
class A { // fails with IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: can't serialize class X in line 234 of org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    Map<String, X> map = new HashMap<String, X>()
}

class B { // works
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>()
}

class C { // works with primitive type values
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>()
}

class X {
    String data

    public X(String data) {
        this.data = data
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more context? Are these domain classes? Which plugin are you using that maps GORM to MongoDB?

Comment: Yes, A, B, C and X are all domain classes. The intention is for A, B, and C to be primary domain classes and for X to be an embedded one. 
I'm using the mongodb Grails plugin:
http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The embedding works perfectly,as Art Hanzel advised.

However your problem comes from the fact that you try and use List genericity as a sort of constraint :

```
Map<String, X>
```

The problem is that Grails couldn't cope well with this syntax, first because [Groovy doesn't support genericity](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics).

However, the MongoDB plugin offers a very powerful functionality that lets you define custom type as Domain Class Properties : [see here](http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html#3.6%20Custom%20User%20Types).

In your case you could have

```
class A {
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    MyClass map = new MyClass()
}
```

Then in your src/java for example you could for example implement a

```
class MyClass extends HashMap<String,X> { }
```

Then, of course, you have to define a special AbstractMappingAwareCustomTypeMarshaller to specify how to read and write the property in the DB.

An additional step could also be to add a custom validator to class A to check the validity of data...

Comment: I'd call this not working out of the box for embedded Maps.  It's very convenient that their docs simply don't show any examples of embedded Maps and claim "it works".  Overall I'd call this a design defect with the way GORM MongoDB plugin was written.  The quality of this plugin is C-.

Comment: Not only is your comment irrelevant to the question asked, but also in this case the design issue comes from the way Groovy itself handles the maps, not from the Mongo plugin.

Comment: I stand by my comment.  The plugin doesn't handle the fact that Groovy doesn't understand generic types even though its well known issue.  Therefore, there is no way for it to bind to types read back out of the database either because it can't just introspect the provided type, and the data in the database doesn't hold the class attribute.  The MongoDB plugin for Grails is infuriating how many use cases the developers ignored and act like it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB Grails plugin [documentation](http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html) describes how to make embedded documents:

```
class Foo {
    Address address
    List otherAddresses
    static embedded = ['address', 'otherAddresses']
}
```

Off the top of my head, you should be able to access these via the object graph. I don't see any reason why you shouldn't.

```
myFoo.address.myAddressProperty...
```

Comment: The only example they show is with a List (as my example B). I'd like to use a Map and that doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: The "address" object will be exposed as a map (Groovy blurs the line between objects and maps). The "otherAddresses" embeds a List of objects. Again, read the doc.